# listview - access viewHolder elements on item click

Tags: android, listview

I have a customAdapter with a viewHolder which contains a customView(circle shape)
I need to retrieve the color of the view which is contained in the view holder and not the Object item

How can i do this ?
Thank you very much

My adapter:

```
public class WelcomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// contex
private Context context;

// Liste a affichée
private RealmList<Measure> welcomeList;

public RealmList<WelcomeList> getWelcomeList() {
    return welcomeList;
}

private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

private int color1;
private int color2;
private int color3;



public WelcomeAdapter (Context context, RealmList<Welcome> welcomeList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.welcomeList= welcomeList;

    color1= ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green);
    color2= ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yellow);
    color3= ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blue);


    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return welcomeList== null ? 0 : welcomeList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return welcomeList== null ? null : welcomeList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_welcome, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.cs = (CircleShape) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_welcome_cv);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Welcome welcome= WelcomeList.get(position);



    if (welcome.getWelcomePeople() != null) {
        for (People p : welcome.getWelcomePeople()) {
            if (p.getNumber() > 5) {
                 viewHolder.cs.setColor(color1);
            } else if (p.getNumber() > 15) {
                 viewHolder.cs.setColor(color2);
            } else if (p.getNumber() > 25) {
                 viewHolder.cs.setColor(color3);
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

 class ViewHolder {
    CircleShape cs;

}
```

The activity

```
protected AdapterView.OnItemClickListener welcomeClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // need to retrieve the current color of the CircleShape of the view holder associated with the item clicked there

        }
    };
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to retrieve the view holder by calling `getTag()` on the view being returned to you, since you are setting the tag to the view holder, using `convertView.setTag(viewHolder)`

Therefore, your `onItemClick` method to get the `CircleShape` should look as follows:

```
ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
CircleShape cs = vh.cs;
```

Let me know if that works, I'm a bit rusty with adapters.

Comment: Correct answer. Also you need to ensure that either `Activity` and `Adapter` are in the same package (because OP's current `ViewHolder` has a package-protected visibility) or make `ViewHolder` a public class.